# Boot to lock screen with encryption

Tags: lock-screens, encryption

After upgrading to Android 5 on my Nexus 10, I've now gone the extra step and enabled encryption. One thing that bothers me though: It doesn't boot to lock screen any more.

I get asked my lock screen code early in the boot process - which is fine - but then after the boot, the device is immediately unlocked. I'd like to boot to the lock screen instead.

Is that possible with a (rooted) stock ROM? I wouldn't mind messing with system files to achieve this, but of course an option somewhere or an app would be nicer.